# TypeScript Vuex Plugin "incompatible types"

Tags: typescript, vuex

Having trouble creating a vuex plugin for a vuex store using TypeScript. The plugin utilises a higher order function in order to take parameters, as depicted below:

Plugin.ts

```
export const ParamsPlugin = 
       () => {
            (store: Store<RootState>) => {
                console.log("ParamsPlugin");
            } 
        }
```

Index.ts

```
const store :StoreOptions<RootState> = {
    state: <RootState> {
      ...
    },
    mutations: {
      ...
    },
    modules: {
      ...
    },
     plugins:  [ ParamsPlugin() ]
  }
```

The Typescript error:

> Types of property 'plugins' are incompatible. Type 'void[]' is not
>   assignable to type 'Plugin[] | undefined'. Type 'void[]' is not
>   assignable to type 'Plugin[]'. Type 'void' is not assignable to type
>   'Plugin'.

I realise this is a TypeScript issue and being new to TypeScript It would be great to know the best way to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your `ParamsPlugin` is a function that does not return anything (`() => void`), so , when you do `ParamsPlugin()` you basically have `void`. TypeScript expects that the `plugins` array have objects that are of type `Plugin`, not `void`.

Though I don't know what `Plugin` is, it might work if you remove the brackets:

```
export const ParamsPlugin = 
   () => (store: Store<RootState>) => {
            console.log("ParamsPlugin");
         }
```

When using arrow functions, if you use brackets you must use `return` to return something. The return is only implicit if instead of a code block after `=>` you put an expression.

Now, `ParamsPlugin()` returns `(Store<RootState>) => void` instead of just `void`.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much for that explanation. That has resolved my issue.